# VBA code : Column index

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet where I import some lines from an other sheet and where I want to add a column that contain an index to each line. This index should be incremented ( 1,2,3,etc until the last line imported).
I prefer that it would be  inserted with the macro "import".
Can someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

`Worksheet.UsedRange` is what you are looking for, I think.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim y As Long

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet     ' or whichever

For y = 1 To sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ' Replace 5 by the column number you want the index in
    sh.Cells(y, 5) = y
Next y
```